# Importing a CSV file that has pipe characters. Error says truncation

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, truncation

I am not the sharpest tool in the shed so please bear with me. I am attempting to import a csv file into Microsoft SQL Server 2016. However, whenever I try to do this I hit upon an error. I think it might have something to do with the pipe characters. The website I got the file from had this to say:

text fields are surrounded by the pipe character (ascii 124).  Date and numeric fields are not.  Commas separate all fields.

Here is what my query looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE cands16 (
    [Cycle] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [FECCandID] [char] (9) NOT NULL,
    [CID] [char] (9) NULL,
    [FirstLastP] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Party] [char] (1) NULL,
    [DistIDRunFor] [char] (4) NULL,
    [DistIDCurr] [char] (4) NULL,
    [CurrCand] [char] (1) NULL,
    [CRPICO] [char] (1) NULL,
    [RecipCode] [char] (2) NULL,
    [NoPacs] [char] (1) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


BULK
INSERT cands16
FROM 'C:\aaa open secrets\CampaignFin16\Cands16.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Here is my error:

```
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 3, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 4, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 5, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 6, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 7, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 8, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 9, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 10, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 11, column 1 (Cycle).
Msg 4865, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Cannot bulk load because the maximum number of errors (10) was exceeded.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 19
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Here is a baby version of my CSV file:

```
|2016|,|H4GA02060|,|N00035294|,|Greg Duke (R)|,|R|,|GA02|,|    |,|Y|,|Y|,|C|,|RC|,| |
|2016|,|H4GA02078|,|N00036257|,|Vivian Childs (R)|,|R|,|GA02|,|    |,| |,| |,| |,|RN|,| |
|2016|,|H4GA04116|,|N00035798|,|Thomas Brown (D)|,|D|,|GA04|,|    |,| |,| |,| |,|DN|,| |
|2016|,|H4GA04124|,|N00035862|,|Thomas Wight (D)|,|D|,|GA07|,|    |,| |,| |,| |,|DN|,| |
|2016|,|H4GA06087|,|N00026160|,|Tom Price (R)|,|R|,|GA06|,|GA06|,|Y|,|Y|,|I|,|RW|,| |
|2016|,|H4GA08067|,|N00026163|,|Lynn A Westmoreland (R)|,|R|,|GA03|,|GA03|,| |,|Y|,|I|,|RI|,| |
|2016|,|H4GA09065|,|N00036258|,|Bernard Fontaine (R)|,|R|,|GA09|,|    |,| |,|Y|,|C|,|RL|,| |
|2016|,|H4GA10071|,|N00035370|,|Mike Collins (R)|,|R|,|GA10|,|    |,| |,| |,| |,|RN|,| |
|2016|,|H4GA11046|,|N00035321|,|Susan Davis (R)|,|R|,|GA11|,|    |,| |,| |,| |,|RN|,| |
```

Comment: I have had that problem as well. Do you create the table as part of the import process? If so, try to create the table first instead using either create table syatement or by using  a wizard. Make sure that the lenght of each column is big enough to host the content.

Comment: @FredrikRudberg I created the table so I could put the imported data into it. I got the instructions for making this table from the website that gave me the content. The website also specified how long each column needs to be to hold the content. Can you show me how to create the table using the edit create table statement? I

Comment: The error message tells me that the column size is not enough

Comment: @FredrikRudberg if that is what the error is saying then the website might have been mistaken. I will increase the column capacity

Comment: @FredrikRudberg you are both a champion and a scholar sir. Your solution worked. It appears that these silly pipes counted as characters. The column lengths the website recommended didn't take the pipes into account. I will have to open another question to ask how to deal with them. Please post your comment as an answer so I can upvote it and give you proper credit for answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The porblem concerns the size of the columns. The import feature is warning that a truncation will have to be made during import with lost data as result.

Increase the size of the table columns or remove the pipe character.

Answer (score 0):

In the next version of SQL Server, you can use `FIELDQUOTE` character as well.  This is kindly [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) on the page that describes the version since SQL Server 2008, probably to confuse casual readers:

```
BULK INSERT cands16
    FROM 'C:\aaa open secrets\CampaignFin16\Cands16.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
      FIELDQUOTE = '|'
     );
```

In the mean time, my best advice is to load the data into a staging table and then parse the columns out into separate columns by removing the first and last characters.

You can simplify this a bit by using `'|,|'` as the field separator and just changing the values in the first and last column.

Comment: I tried your method. It says: Incorrect syntax near 'FIELDQUOTE'. It should be noted that the word FIELDQUOTE didn't turn blue like I expected it to

Comment: Also do I have to put the semicolon in after the closing parenthesis?

Comment: @anang . . . The semicolon is optional but recommended.  It identifies that a statement has ended.

Comment: I was thinking that if I throw in the semicolon then the GO after the parenthesis won't register. Also, is FIELDQUOTE used in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: @anang . . . I think this is the version after 2016.

Comment: really? I didn't know that the next SQL Server was already out. I am using 2016. Do you know what I should put in for 2016 version?